# Are there speculative ETFs analogous to investment funds?

Tags: etf, index-fund, risk, volatility, speculation

Are there ETFs that bundle up highly speculative investments with high risk/reward profiles?

For instance, they might currently include Zambian, Nigerian, Brazilian and Venezuelan bonds; cryptocurrency-related equity; Russell 2000 penny stocks, and the like.

It might also include special derivatives, based, for example, on countries with very low GDP.

Because of the volatility, I assume that they would not operate like investment funds, but would need to constantly adapt their portfolio.

Comment: Russell 2000 penny stocks?

Comment: I don't know about bundled ETFs but there are some horrific losers this year such as Bitcoin, Brazil, Latin America, VIX, and a number of 3x leveraged funds (short oil).

Comment: Russell 2000 penny stocks. Former components soon to trade on the pink sheets? :->)